# How to look like Sonar Online Dashboard?

Tags: sonarqube

I see a big difference in the *look & feel* between the **online dashboard**  (https://sonarqube.com/projects or https://sonarqube.com/governance?id=MASTER_PROJECT) and the one that we see by default on our local installation of sonar (v5.6.3).

I'm wondering about whether the online look & feel can in someway be easily applied to a local installation. It's just a matter of css/js or behind we have also a completely different HTML structure?

Any information about this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found the answer to my question. The nice-looking online demo is based on an Enterprise Grade deployment of sonar with the governance plugin.

https://www.sonarsource.com/why-us/products/plugins/governance.html
https://www.sonarsource.com/solutions/deployments/enterprise-grade/

Answer (score 1):

Can't you update your install to the latest version? There have been UI changes in both version 6.0 and 6.1

http://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-6-0-in-screenshots/

http://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-6-1-in-screenshots/

Comment: Thanks Gary, however I don't think the update brings the changes I'm referring to. For example if you go to https://sonarqube.com/governance?id=MASTER_PROJECT you'll see a nice dashboard reporting for all projects. It does not seem we have something similar in the default installation. Do we need some plugin or specific configuration?